# error "Uncaught Error: Script error for: popper.js"

Tags: magento2

I'm getting an error related to popper and I don't remember what this file was, has anyone been through this? I would be grateful if you would help me. It looks like this file doesn't exist, but I don't know how to fix it...

```
 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)        popper.js.
    Uncaught Error: Script error for: popper.js
    http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
        at makeError (require.js:166)
        at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:1677)
```

Comment: Have you try to disable all third party extension one by one and check this one.